# How do I ask the user for String inputs ? (if they want to enter center and radius, or endpoints of diameter?) (Read an input)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

// this is the driver and there are resource classes called/used

ignorethislineofwriting
ignorethislineofwriting
ignorethislineofwriting
ignorethislineofwriting

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class KI23CriclesDriver
    {
       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
          //Declare Variables
          int x1, y1, x2, y2;
          String print;
          double center;
          double center2;
          String radius;
          int validLength = 1;
          int validLength2 = 2;

          //Instantiate Objects
          KI23GetC gc = new KI23GetC();
          KI23GetCircles gs = new KI23GetCircles();
          KI23PrintC p = new KI23PrintC();
          System.out.println("Do you want to enter (Option 1) center and radius or (Option 2) end points of diameter?");
          x1 = 0;
          y1 = 0;
          x2 = 0;
          y2 = 0;
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          radius = scanner.nextLine();
          if( radius.length() == validLength )
          {
             System.out.println("Please enter the center and radius");
             x2 = gc.getX();
             y2 = gc.getY();
             x1 = gc.getX();
             y1 = gc.getY();
             center = gs.getCenter(x1, y1, x2, y2);
             center2 = gs.getCenter2(x1, y1, x2, y2);  
             p.print(x1, y1, x2, y2, center, center2);
          }

          if( radius.length() == validLength2) // doesnt work since validlength2 is the same as validlength
          {
             System.out.println("Please enter the end points of diameter");
             x1 = gc.getX();
             y1 = gc.getY();
             x2 = gc.getX();
             y2 = gc.getY();
             center = gs.getCenter(x1, y1, x2, y2);
             center2 = gs.getCenter2(x1, y1, x2, y2);  
             p.print(x1, y1, x2, y2, center, center2);

          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2");
             x1 = 0;
             y1 = 0;
             x2 = 0;
             y2 = 0;
             radius = scanner.nextLine();  
          }
    //
```

//I want a better way to take in inputs and do different decisions and calculations upon that
           }
        }

Comment: I tend to use an InputReader, but I learned before Scanner.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to do and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've obviously not shown all of your code for this and other classes therefore the example code below basically utilizes what you've provided...to some extent. The prompts are broken up and provided within specific class methods. The **main()** method only calls another method which actually starts the ball rolling (so to speak). This is done to avoid the need for statics.

The **startApp()** method calls the **mainMenu()** method which in turn displays the Main Menu for this console application. The menu is contained within a loop to ensure a proper entry is done by the User.

The option selected from the Main Menu is returned from the **mainMenu()** method as an integer value which then falls into the control of a **switch/case** block which in turn determines whether a Center and Radius (menu item **1**) is to be supplied or Circle End Points (menu item **2**) are to be supplied.

If a Center and Radius is to be supplied then the **getCenterAndRadius()** method is called which prompts the user to supply a Center value and a Radius value.

If a Circle End Points are to be supplied then the **getCircleEndPoints()** method is called which prompts the user to supply all four values (x1, y1, x2, y2) to make up the two required end points for the circle.

An additional method named **getCenterAndRadius_2()** is also made available which demonstrates yet another way to allow a User to supply End Point values. Use the one that suits you the best or, create you own methods based on some ideas given within the code.

Use of [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) are used within the provided code. The [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm), [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm), and the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) methods utilize these Regular Expressions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KI23CriclesDriver {

    // KI23GetC gc = new KI23GetC();
    // KI23GetCircles gs = new KI23GetCircles();
    // KI23PrintC p = new KI23PrintC();

    private final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    private int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Done this way to avoid statics
        new KI23CriclesDriver().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        int menuOption = mainMenu();
        switch (menuOption) {
            case 1:
                getCenterAndRadius();
                break;
            case 2:
                getCircleEndPoints();
                // getCircleEndPoints_2();
                break;
        }
    }

    private int mainMenu() {
        int menuChoice = 0;
        while (menuChoice == 0) {
            System.out.println("Supply a circle creation option:");
            System.out.println("  1) Based on Center and Radius." + ls
                             + "  2) Based on Diameter End Points.");
            System.out.print("Choice: --> ");
            String choice = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            if (choice.toLowerCase().startsWith("q")) {
                // Quit appplication
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (!choice.matches("[12]")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid menu choice! Try again..." + ls);
                continue;
            }
            menuChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        }
        return menuChoice;
    }

    private void getCenterAndRadius() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Center and Radius:");
        String center = "", radius = "";
        // Center
        while (center.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("Center Value: --> ");
            center = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!center.matches("\\d+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry for CENTER! Try again...");
                center = "";
            }
        }
        // Radius
        while (radius.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("Radius Value: --> ");
            radius = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!radius.matches("\\d+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry for RADIUS! Try again...");
                radius = "";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(new StringBuffer("").append("Center = ").append(center)
                           .append("  |  Radius = ").append(radius));

        /* Do what you want here with the numerical values
           contained within the String variables center and 
           radius. 
        */
    }

    private void getCircleEndPoints() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Circle End Points:");
        String xx1 = "", yy1 = "", xx2 = "", yy2 = "";
        // x1
        while (xx1.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("x1 Value: --> ");
            xx1 = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!xx1.matches("\\d+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry for x1! Try again...");
                xx1 = "";
            }
        }
        // y1
        while (yy1.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("y1 Value: --> ");
            yy1 = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!yy1.matches("\\d+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry for y1! Try again...");
                yy1 = "";
            }
        }
        // x2
        while (xx2.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("x2 Value: --> ");
            xx2 = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!xx2.matches("\\d+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry for x2! Try again...");
                xx2 = "";
            }
        }
        // y2
        while (yy2.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("y2 Value: --> ");
            yy2 = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!yy2.matches("\\d+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry for y2! Try again...");
                yy2 = "";
           }
        }

        System.out.println(new StringBuffer("").append("Circle End Points Suplied: (")
                           .append(xx1).append(",").append(yy1).append("), (")
                           .append(xx2).append(",").append(yy2).append(")"));

        /* Do what you want here with the numerical values
           contained within the String variables xx1, yy1, 
           xx2, and yy2.
        */
    }

    private void getCircleEndPoints_2() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Circle End Points:" + ls
                         + "Example Entries: 50 50 65 72 or" + ls
                         + "                 50,50,65,72 or" + ls
                         + "                 50, 50, 65, 72");

        int xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2;
        String endPoints = "";
        while (endPoints.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("End Points: --> ");
            endPoints = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!endPoints.replaceAll("[ ,]","").matches("\\d+") || 
                            endPoints.contains(",") ? endPoints.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}").length != 4 
                            : endPoints.split("\\s+").length != 4) {
                System.err.println("Invalid End Points Entry! Try again...");
                endPoints = "";
            }
        }
        String[] points = endPoints.contains(",") ? 
                          endPoints.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}") : 
                          endPoints.split("\\s+");
        xx1 = Integer.parseInt(points[0]);
        yy1 = Integer.parseInt(points[1]);
        xx2= Integer.parseInt(points[2]);
        yy2 = Integer.parseInt(points[3]);

        System.out.println(new StringBuffer("").append("Circle End Points Suplied: (")
                           .append(xx1).append(",").append(yy1).append("), (")
                           .append(xx2).append(",").append(yy2).append(")"));

        /* Do what you want here with the numerical values
           contained within the int type variables xx1, yy1, 
           xx2, and yy2.
        */
    }
}
```

> **Regular Expressions Used In Code:**

```
if (!choice.matches("[12]")) {
```

The `"[12]"` expression contained here within the **matches()** method of this **if** condition basically means this: If the supplied string contained within the **choice** variable is **not** either "1" or "2" then enter the **if** code block.

---

```
if (!center.matches("\\d+")) {
```

The `"\\d+"` expression contained here within the **matches()** method of this **if** condition basically means this: If the supplied string contained within the **center** variable is **not** a string representation of one or more numerical digits (0 to 9) then enter the **if** code block.

You can see this expression used in several places.

---

```
endPoints.replaceAll("[ ,]", "")
```

The `"[ ,]"` expression contained here within the **replaceAll()** method means replace *all* whitespaces (" ") and commas (,) from the string contained within the **endPoints** string variable.

---

```
endPoints.split("\\s+")
```

The `"\\s+"` expression contained here within the **split()** method means: split the string contained within the **endPoints** variable into a String Array based on one or more whitespace (" ") delimiters

---

```
endPoints.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}")
```

The `"\\s{0,},\\s{0,}"` expression contained here within the **split()** method means: split the string contained within the **endPoints** variable into a String Array based on comma (",") delimiters OR **any** comma/whitespace combination delimiter (ex:  "," or ", " or " ," or " , ") regardless of the number of whitespaces (if any) on either side of the comma. It basically covers all the bases for comma delimiter usage.

---

Modify the code as you see fit.